# Azure SQL: Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal [USERNAME] does not exist

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

I currently have 10 SQL databases in Azure. In the Azure Portal I have my username (omnipos).

When I want to connect to the databases with MSSM I got the error

Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "[USERNAME]" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15517)

However the web apps that are using these databases are working fine (with the same username and password).

Firewall in Azure is set up correctly. During months I could connect to these databases with Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web but since today it isn't working anymore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you let me know when this is fixed? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

a nice call from Microsoft Azure support, apparently this is a known issue occurring in the last few days where the database default setting in the "Connect to database" on the "Connection Properties" tab on the connection screen no longer functions (apparently there is an issue between this and the master schema). If you enter your database name in here the problem will go away and you can manage your database again.

A fix is a couple of weeks away but I think they are releasing a statement soon :-)